# Remove HTML from attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need remove HTML `<br>` from `data-original-title`

**HTML:**

```
<abbr class="small text-c-muted" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Cena bez DPH<br> 1&nbsp;652,89&nbsp;Kč">s DPH</abbr>
```

I need the remove `<br>` because I'm using CSS `::after` on the page which references within `content: attr(data-original-title);`, but unfortunately I'm taking it over including the given `<br>` which I'd need to remove.
I can´t edit source code. I can use just CSS and JS.

**JavaScript:**
If I try to insert JavaScript, this notation does not take the page and returns it
**in console error:**
"Uncaught Type Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading "replace").

```
$('abbr.small').text(function(_,txt) {return $(this).attr('data-original-title').replace('<br>','');});
```

Any idea how to remove `<br>`?

I tried JavaScript with replace, but not working. I need to remove `<br>`

Comment: Your code works fine *when* the `abbr.small` has the required attribute.  If it doesn't then you just need to check for null, eg:  `return ($(this).attr('data-original-title') || "").replace(/<br>/, ' ');`

Answer (score 1):

jQuery Solution:

```
$('abbr.small').attr('data-original-title', $(this).attr('data-original-title').replace('<br>',''));
```

Plain javascript solution:

```
let element = document.querySelector('abbr.small');

element.setAttribute('data-original-title', element.getAttribute('data-original-title').replaceAll('<br>', ''));
```

if you have multiple elements you should use **querySelectorAll** instead of **querySelector** and loop through the items using for loop or forEach loop

```
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('abbr.small');

elements.forEach(element => {
    element.setAttribute('data-original-title', element.getAttribute('data-original-title').replaceAll('<br>', ''));
})
```

Comment: `$('abbr.small').attr('data-original-title', $('abbr.small')...` will only work if there's only one abbr.small, which seems unlikely.  Should use `this`, at which point your code will have the same problem as OP's.